# Connecting PowerSW and Reset SW

Tags: motherboard, computer-building

I am trying to build my first NAS and need help to connect the power SW and the Reset SW.

This is an ASRock B85m Pro4 montherboard. The attached image is what I found in the manual. I put the numbers in red to make it clear.

Both Reset SW and Power SW have 2 wires, one is red and one is blank.

For Power SW, I think I need to use 3 and 4, but not sure which number should be red which number should be black.

For Reset SW, I am lost, not sure if I should use 7 and 8 or 8 and 9. Also not sure which color should go with which number.

[image: ASRock B85m Pro4 manual]

Comment: I'm not an EE, but in my experience it's the opposite - black is nearly always ground...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter in this context, since the power and reset switches are just momentary switches that short the pins together. The polarity is only important for the LEDs.